# How can I change the height of one static cell | Swift

Tags: swift

Essentially I would like to hide a cell in my static table when two conditionals are met:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    var height: CGFloat
    if indexPath.row == 1 && unitImage == nil {
        height = 0
    } else {
     height = 190
        }
    
    return height
}
```

The issue is each of the cells have a different height set in story board and I really only need to hide the first row if unitImage is blank.

Comment: Can you explain something more about this... What does it mean by each cell has different height in storyboard ?? aren't you specifying height at the runtime ?

Comment: Usually static cells are driven by outlets, not by datasource and delegate.

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I do like below code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    
    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row  {
            return 288
        } else {
            return 56
        }
 
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        
        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
            return 160
        } else {
            return 56
        }
 
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        
        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row  {
            return 1576
        } else {
            return 56
        }
 
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Where selected index is my selected cell index so please change that as per your requriement.